# Why my PHP include function not working correctly?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have this PHP code --

```
<?php include('res/scripts/php/content_type/form_contents/birth_date_form.php?type=register&query=birth_month'); ?>
```

As you can see I'm including `?type` and `&query` in it, so is it wrong or there is something else which going wrong. Because it shows me the following error---

```
Warning: include(res/scripts/php/content_type/form_contents/birth_date_form.php?type=register&query=birth_month) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No error in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysharepoint\1.1\res\scripts\php\content_type\register_form.php on line 82

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'res/scripts/php/content_type/form_contents/birth_date_form.php?type=register&query=birth_month' for inclusion (include_path='.;\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysharepoint\1.1\res\scripts\php\content_type\register_form.php on line 82
```

But after removing `?type=register&query=birth_month`, I get no errors!
So do you have any suggestions on this, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you trying to load the file as php - then run the script, or load the content that the script generates after being run?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to include as if it is served via the web, but include will simply load the local file - so there is no query string as no processing takes place

---

Furthermore - if you are trying to get an external url to be output from your script, you could do something like this:

```
echo implode(file('http://localhost/res/scripts/php/content_type/form_contents/birth_date_form.php?type=register&query=birth_month'))
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot include a URL with query string via relative path.  If you need to specify the query string, do it as a full absolute URL:

```
include('http://www.example.com/res/scripts/php/content_type/form_contents/birth_date_form.phptype=register&query=birth_month');
```

This requires `allow_url_fopen` to be on.

Comment: And how to do this? I'm new to PHP. Please help me out.

Comment: You mean `allow_url_fopen` ? It is a configuration directive in php.ini. http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php

Comment: This helped Michael! I would keep this is mind and thanks for providing me a new site for PHP training!

Answer (score 1):

PHP is going to look for the file name 'birth_date_form.php?type=register&query=birth_month' which does not exist.

You can pass the variables to your script using in the called url directly, and call birth_date_form.php instead.

That should work.